# FileChoose is being opened twice

Tags: java, javafx

I don´t know why, but if I click on submit or cancel, a second window of `showOpenDialog()` opens. I tried `JFileChooser` but there was the same problem.

```
 private void menuAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FileChooser file = new FileChooser();
    file.setTitle("Suche eine Datei");
    try {
        do {
            String row;
            File userDir = new File("/home/tom/Dokumente/Lernfragen");
            file.setInitialDirectory(userDir);
            File selected = file.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (selected != null){
                FileReader getData = new FileReader(selected);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(getData);

                this.questions = new ArrayList();
                this.answers = new ArrayList();
                while ((row = br.readLine()) != null){
                    if (row.contains("Q:"))
                        if (!spacesToQA(row).equals(""))
                            this.questions.add(spacesToQA(row));


                    if (row.contains("A:"))
                        if (!spacesToQA(row).equals(""))
                            this.answers.add(spacesToQA(row));


                }
                txtAsk.setText(this.questions.get(rnd.nextInt(this.questions.size()-1)));

            } else{
                System.out.println("Keine Datei angegeben!");
                break;
            }


        } while ((this.answers.size() != this.questions.size()));    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("null !");
    }    

}
```

Kind regards.

Comment: What type of action is calling your function?

Comment: You are opening the `FileChooser` in a loop. Check that this condition is being met: `(this.answers.size() != this.questions.size())`.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was this

```
    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#menuAction" text="File">
      <items>
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#menuAction" text="Laden" fx:id="menuItemLoad" />
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Schließen" fx:id="menuItemClose" />
      </items>
    </Menu>
```

I had 2 onAction attr in this case. Problem fixed, thanks for the fast answers.

kind regards

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the check next to the answer so others don't think this is still open